# Get data-id variable from Django POST request

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

My template:

```
<h1 data-post-id="{{ obj.id }}"></h1>
```

views

```
id = request.POST.get('post-id')
print('ID:', id) #prints None
```

How can I get access the `post-id` data attribute in my python/django views?

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: you can send only form name elements value

Comment: Yes I am using ajax

Comment: post the ajax code

Comment: The ajax is working as I am receiving other post requests. However none of them are `data-id` attributes

Comment: Then the Ajax code is *not* working. Data attributes are not sent in post requests, you need to add them there yourself in the JS code. You should post that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `post-id` in your view, you must ensure that it is provided as a parameter in your POST request. You can do this through AJAX or a HTML form.

Via Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourformviewurl',
    data: {
      'post-id': $("#yourh1id").attr('data-post-id')
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('it worked!', data)
    }
  });
```

Via HTML Form:

```
   <form action="/yourformviewurl" method="post">
       <label for="post-id">Post id: </label>
       <input id="post-id" type="text" name="post-id" value="{{ obj.id }}">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Please see the Django form docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/